# Multiple SecurityFilterChain beans created in loop

Tags: spring-boot, security, spring-security, spring-resource-server

Create `SecurityFilterChain` in `@Configuration` class as standard `@Bean` and `@Order` is easy.
I need add `factoryMethod` to the `@Configuration`. I don't know how to run this factory method injecting properties, `HttpSecurity` bean multiple times and add it to security context.

My problem:
I have `Map` of properties with `tenant-name` and `issuer-uri`, for each tenant I need create separate `SecurityFilterChain` based on matcher "/tenant-name/**" and oauth2 issuer-url.

My doubts:
When I use custom constructor and inject there `ApplicationContext`, my properties, `HttpSecurity`.
Write injected `HttpSecurity` to local variable and use it multiple times will configure child's child securityMatcher on any incrementation instead of root matcher. Am I right?
I'm not sure register bean to Application context will be enough to work with spring security.

What is the best and appropriate solution in your opinion to solve this problem? I don't know Spring Security enough so I need a little help.

Comment: Why would you need a separate configuration for that? Instead write a custom oauth2 component that selects the right issuer url.

Comment: I need only one issuer for different url groups instead of multiple issuers for any url.

Comment: I can add custom resolver for that it is true, thanks. In other hand using builder for configuration is very short and more readable in few lines of the same file.
Using RequestMatcherDelegatingAuthenticationManagerResolver and adapt JwtAuthenticationProvider as AuthenticationManager to the resolver looks crazy, when configuration by register few beans with securityMatcher looks so easy.

Comment: It looks easier but it isn't. The multiple filters are more complex then just a single entrypoint.

Comment: I'm trying with FilterChainProxy, but I don't know how to use HttpSecurity multiple times without injecting.

Comment: Don't, just configure oauth to determine based on the tenant to use the roper URL. Don't try to solve this with multiple filter chains. \

Comment: Should I use `RequestMatcherDelegatingAuthenticationManagerResolver` and implements `AuthenticationManager` into `JwtAuthenticationProvider` and do the same for others like public and basic?
How to configure it easy?

Comment: I can't just add other local configuration of oauth in code. It is security library for other apps based on properties. In properties is map of all tenants. Simplifying the concept there key is the tenant name and base directory of url, but value is the issuer-uri.
Latest form should use `org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.oauth2.resource.OAuth2ResourceServerProperties` instead of `issuer-uri` or `jwk-set-uri` only.